# Measure performance of a multiples classifier that is a combination of binary support vector machines

Tags: svm, multi-class, model-evaluation

I am comparing the performance of multiple schemes to combine binary SVMs into one multiples classifier. I was hoping to use the cross entropy, however I cannot figure out how to apply it.

For example, if you use the One-Against-One combination scheme, you get $\frac{K(K - 1)}{2}$ SVMs, where $K$ is the number of classes. Of these $\frac{k(k - 1)}{2}$ classifiers only $(k - 1)$ actually say something about in which class a certain pattern $\vec{x}$ falls. For example the output of the SVM that discriminates class $A$ from class $B$ does not have a defined output for class $C$. It seemed to me, that to compute the cross-entropy you would only have to consider the target outputs and actual outputs of the SVMs that say something about the actual class of the pattern. According to Duda et al. the cross-entropy for a multiples problem is:

$$
J(\vec{x}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{K} t_{n, k} \ln \left( \frac{t_{n,k}}{z_{n,k}} \right).
$$
Where $t_{n,k}$ is the target label of pattern $n$ of the in total $N$ classes for classifier $k$, which is one of the $K - 1$ classifiers that are relevant for $\vec{x}$. The scalar $z_{n,k}$ represents the output of the binary classifier $k$ on pattern $n$. (This is the distance measure scaled with Platt-scaling to get a probability.)

According to Duda et al. $t_{n,k}, z_{n,k} \in [0,1]$, however my target labels are either zero or one. If the target label is zero, then the result of $\ln \left( \frac{t_{n,k}}{z_{n,k}} \right)$ is $-\infty$. However if we use that $-\infty .\cdot 0 = 0$ this does not matter.

It seems to me that this is the way to compute the cross entropy, however I make a lot of assumptions, and I cannot find any use of the cross-entropy in the context I described. Thus my question is, should I use the cross-entropy to measure performance in this case? If so, am I doing it correctly, if not what measure should I use and why?